# Dynamics AX 2009 Mobile C#

Tags: c#, mobile, axapta, dynamics-ax-2009

I have to develop a mobile application on a motorola mc55a0 device, running windows mobile 6.5. The thing is I need to connect to AX 2009 and since I can't use the business connector in a mobile app, i don't know where to start...

Any help is appreciated. Thanks

Comment: Maybe you could access AIF services? That said, it seems like an uphill battle to make apps for a 5 year old deprecated mobile OS.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

We have a mobile app on Windows Mobile 6.5 too, same sort of device. We have a version both for AX 2009 and AX 2012. With AX 2009 we use the business connector, with AX 2012 we use WCF services.

What I would do in your case is create services in .NET that connect to AX using the business connector. You can then deploy these services, for example on IIS (which is what we did). You can then create a client for Windows Mobile 6.5 (using the Compact Framework) and connect to those services you created.

I understand you have the need to create an app for this old operating system. Many devices used in for example warehouses run on Windows Mobile 6.5 of even CE (I don't agree with the down votes).

I hope you know here to start know. I'm no .net specialist so I cannot help you with creating those services or that client, but the architecture I described works for us so it should work for you too.

One thing you should keep in mind is that you will have to implement some kind of connection pooling for the business connector in your service because otherwise there will be too much overhead logging on to AX with the BC all of the time.

Comment: Thanks for answering, I'll follow your advice.